# Angular routing redirects to parent route instead of child on page refresh

Tags: angular, angular-router

I have the following app routing:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children:
      [
        {
          path: '',
          redirectTo: '/dashboard',
          pathMatch: 'full'
        },
        {
          path: 'dashboard',
          component: DashboardComponent,
          children:
            [
              {path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent},
              {path: 'user-management', component: UserManagementComponent},
              {path: 'role-management', component: RoleManagementComponent}
            ]
        }
      ]
  },
  {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
  {path:'token-verify',component:TwoFactorVerificationComponent}
];
```

So here is my problem .Let's say I am on route `dashboard`.Navigating to `/profile` or `/user-management` works fine using the angular router.However I am facing the following problem If I am on route `/dashboard/user-management` or `/dashboard/role-management` and do a page refresh I will get redirected to `/dashboard/profile`. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Here is my auth quard

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import {
  CanActivate,
  ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  RouterStateSnapshot
} from "@angular/router";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { UserService } from "../services/user.service";
import { TokenService } from "../services/token.service";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    private tokenService: TokenService,
    private userService: UserService
  ) {}

  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    console.log(`Requested -> state: ${state.url}`);
    if (this.tokenService.isLoggedIn()) {
      console.log("isLogged in and will return true");
      return true;
    } else {
      console.log("will fail and go to login");
      this.userService.redirectToLogginPage();
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Whenever I do refresh the page the auth guard gets called and it prints

```
Requested -> state: /dashboard/user-management 
auth.guard.ts:26 isLogged in and will return true
```

in case I am logged in

After some digging I found that If I refresh the page on `dashboard/user-management` the OnInit method of that component is actually called but I get redirected in `/dashboard/profile`

Comment: If you change redirectTo: '/dashboard' -> redirectTo: 'dashboard' ?

Comment: @Stefan still the same thing happens

Comment: Ok and now swap your routes that dashboard is first.

Comment: what to you mean ?

Comment: Can you show your AuthGuard, do you perform some redirect there? What is the next route in your guard in this case?

Comment: I only use one auth guard and redirect to login page in case of an expired auth token or if user is logged in .Will update question with auth guard in a couple of minutes

Comment: Can you console log next from AuthGuard?

Comment: Check my updated question in the end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I finally found what was wrong.In the dashboard component (the parent one) this was happening on ngOnInit()

```
ngOnInit() {
    // @TODO
    // refactor using async await
    this.userService
      .getProfile()
      .then((res: any) => {
        console.log(res);
        const user: UserIdentity = res;
        this.user_email = user.emailId;
        if (this.userService.checkrole(user.roles, "ADMIN")) {
          //this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }
```

I removed this line and it worked.The reasonn is that after the child view was rendered the parent view would say "Hey child view go back to the parent view"

Answer (score 1):

```
   const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children:
      [
        {
          path: '',
          redirectTo: '/dashboard',
          pathMatch: 'full'
        },
        {
          path: 'dashboard',
          component: DashboardComponent,
 children: [
                  {path: '', redirectTo: 'profile'},
                  {path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent},
                  {path: 'user-management', component: 
                UserManagementComponent},
                  {path: 'role-management', component: 
                   RoleManagementComponent}
              ]     
   }
      ]
  },
  {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
  {path:'token-verify',component:TwoFactorVerificationComponent}
];
```

Comment: Every component renders without any issues

Comment: Also routing in these components seems to work fine.Problem is if I reload the page when I am in one of these routes

Comment: Try this:children: [
              {path: '', redirectTo: 'profile'},
              {path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent},
              {path: 'user-management', component: UserManagementComponent},
              {path: 'role-management', component: RoleManagementComponent}
    ]

Comment: can you update your answer with respect to my app routing?

Comment: can you provide a full app routing structure?

Comment: ```Error: Invalid configuration of route '{path: "dashboard/", redirectTo: "profile"}': please provide 'pathMatch'. The default value of 'pathMatch' is 'prefix', but often the intent is to use 'full'.```

Comment: I added path match full but the same happens.